# got error code here activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my Activity Class code... i want to click the imagebutton and launch the fragment class, but the problem is i got error on the code in this line

```
BluActivity f = BluActivity.newInstance(index);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail, f).commit();
```

i attach image to see whats my problem about it :( ...

```
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String INDEX = "index";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupImageButton1();
}

private void setupImageButton1(){
    ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bataImg2);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override       
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        int index = i.getIntExtra(INDEX, 0);
        BluActivity f = BluActivity.newInstance(index);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail, f).commit();
        }
    });
    setupImageButton1();
}

    private void setupImageButton3(){
    ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bataImg1);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override           
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

**here is is the error i attach image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RBDf.png

here is the bluactivity class

Answer (score 0):

That was a nightmare replacing your code.

replace your code with my code and do the imports don't create the methods.  Import the methods

```
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String INDEX = "index";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setupImageButton1();
}

private void setupImageButton1(){
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bataImg2);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override       
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = getIntent(); 
    int index = i.getIntExtra(INDEX, 0);
    BluActivity f = BluActivity.newInstance(index);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail, f).commit();
    }
});
setupImageButton1();
}

private void setupImageButton3(){
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bataImg1);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override           
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        }
    });
} 
}
```

Comment: still got error when i import the fragment here sir -> http://i62.tinypic.com/25gqjb4.png

Comment: change it to getFragmentManager()

Comment: Its obvious you don't have a class called BluActivity that extends Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your BluActivity class doesn't seems to extend Fragment.

Change and extend it to Fragment and related changes

Comment: public class BluActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static final String INDEX = "index";

public static BluActivity newInstance(int index) {
    BluActivity f = new BluActivity();
    return f;
    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_blu, null);
 return v;
}

Comment: that is my bluactivity class i already extend that to fragment

Comment: your fragment should extend Fragment and not FragmentActivity